# Does Bokeh API Support 3D Plots?

Tags: api, bokeh

I've been poking around the Bokeh API docs for a few hours, and haven't found anything relevant. So I wanted to ask if anyone knows whether or not the Bokeh API supports 3D ploting (similar to what you can do in matplotlib with `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd have to use [the Surface3d custom model example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/advanced/extensions/wrapping.html).

You won't have to write any JavaScript, but you'll have to copy over the Surface3d class and inline JavaScript, then create your own instance of it.

Comment: I think the question is how to use it. And provide a minimal example.

Comment: What's linked in the docs *is* a minimal example (that's explicitly what I wrote it to be) but it is far too big to include directly inline here. However the question to me asks if there is built in 3d support, and the answer to that is "no" (but you can create your own custom extension)

Comment: do you know why I'm getting "SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal" error? I'm on a Mac, using VSCode.

Comment: too sad bokeh not support 3d plotting